# Which value of accuracy or balanced accuracy is enough?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction, cart, accuracy

I constructed a classification tree and want validate the out of sample performance. I read that the accuracy or the balanced accuracy must at least higher than the no information rate. By the no information rate i mean the accuracy of a model that just predict the class that is the most in the data set. But which values of the accuracy are acceptable? I mean values over 0,7, or 0,8? Is there a rule of thumb or something like that. I didn't find a paper with a scala.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless)

Comment: Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) and [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I do not think that even if the OP used a proper scoring rule like CRPS the issue mentioned would be resolved. I think that the question is about "*how long my piece of string needs to be*"?

Comment: @usεr11852: I think the proposed duplicate answers the question about "how good is good enough" (in exactly the way your answer does, which I upvoted). In addition, I point out that accuracy and similar are not good KPIs in the first place.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I misinterpreted your comment then! Thank you for clarifying! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definite threshold about what is a "good number" because such a threshold would be application specific. If the state of the art is 55% Accuracy and we get 56% we get great. If the state of the art is 99% Accuracy and we get 98.9% we are not doing that great (but maybe we are faster, less memory hungry, etc. etc.).